# Update Histogram Bins with html range slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram

I'm trying to modify the bins of an histogram layout through an html slider, with no success.
The code I tried running for the slider is:

```
<div id = "range">
<input type="range" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="25">
</div>
```

Then I set the `bins` of the histogram to `var bin`.
The js code to update the bins with the value of the range slider:

```
d3.select("#range")
.select("input")
.on("change", function () {
    this.value == bin;
    //The two histogram variables, line and path generators
    histogSans = d3 .layout.histogram()
                        .bins(bin)
                        .value(function (d) { return d.Peso; })
                        (FontSans);
    histogSerif = d3 .layout.histogram()
                        .bins(bin)
                        .value(function (d) { return d.Peso; })
                        (FontSans);
    line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.x); })
            .y(function (d) { return y(d.y); });
    SansPath = svg
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .attr("d", line(histogSans));
});
```

where `histogSans` & `histogSerif` are the generators of the histogram values, `line` is the line generator and `SansPath` & `SerifPath` are the path generators that follow the histogram values.

**EDIT:** thanks to cuckovic I am now able to get the right value out of the slider, with `bin = this.value;`, but the console log of the histogram now returns a wrong array, containing just an array of all the values in the dataset, so the values are not plotted correctly! anyone knows why this happens?
Full code here: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37967455/confronto_pesi.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have to change

```
this.value == bin;
```

to

```
var bin = this.value;
```

Here is working example - http://jsfiddle.net/M3NDv/

Comment: ok this updates the bin var correctly indeed, now I need to figure out why the histograms are not updated

Comment: the full code is here if you want to take a look: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37967455/confronto_pesi.html

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it updated both the axis and the paths, the main issue was that the `range value` was not recognized as `value`, so putting a + in front of it solved, plus other little things. 
Here's the code if anyone is interested:

```
d3.select("#range")
    .select("input")
    .on("change", function () {
        bin = +this.value;
        //Le due variabili di istogramma
        histogSans = d3 .layout.histogram()
                            .bins(bin)
                            .value(function (d) { return d.Peso; })
                            (FontSans);
        histogSerif = d3 .layout.histogram()
                            .bins(bin)
                            .value(function (d) { return d.Peso; })
                            (FontSerif);
        MaxSans = d3.max(histogSans, function (d) { return d.y; });
        MaxSerif = d3.max(histogSerif, function (d) { return d.y; });
        y.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) {
                if ( MaxSans >= MaxSerif )
                    { return MaxSans; }
                else { return MaxSerif; }; 
                })]).nice();
        console.log(MaxSans, MaxSerif);
        gy  .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .call(yAxis);
        line = d3.svg.line()
                .interpolate("monotone")
                .x(function (d) { return x(d.x); })
                .y(function (d) { return y(d.y); });
        SansPath
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("d", line(histogSans));
        SerifPath
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("d", line(histogSerif));
});
```